# How is S4 class definition done in a package and how is it documented properly?

Tags: r, documentation, r-s4

Once I defined a class I wonder where to out in a package. Should just create a file `classDefintions.R` containing my S4 class definition and put it to the R folder? If so, how can I document it properly? Is there a `.rd` file template for S4 classes around?

I found this [post on Roxygen2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368262/how-to-properly-document-s4-class-slots-using-roxygen2) but I might be a few step behind here. How is it basically done and located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like other R objects, S4 class and method definitions are documented with *.Rd files stored in the man subdirectory of the package source.

Besides reading [the relevant section of R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-S4-classes-and-methods), I'd suggest downloading and looking at the source of a well-written S4-based package with which you're familiar. (For me that would likely be **sp**, **lme4** or **Matrix**.)

Finally, the **methods** package includes two nifty utility functions, `promptClass()` and `promptMethods()` that will fill out a skeleton *.Rd file for any S4 class or method defined in the current R session.

As an example that uses R objects defined in the **sp** package, you could do this:

```
library(sp)     ## for some example S4 classes and methods

promptClass("SpatialPolygons")
# A shell of class documentation has been written to the file
# ‘SpatialPolygons-class.Rd’.

promptMethods("bbox")
# A shell of methods documentation has been written to the file
# ‘bbox-methods.Rd’.
```

And then take a look at the files `SpatialPolygons-class.Rd` and `bbox-methods.Rd` to see how much work those functions will save you!

---

**Edit:**  After a quick reread of your question, I see you were also asking about how to include the methods and classes themselves. My advice for that's basically the same: read the manual and "use the source" (making sure to also look at how `exportClasses()` and `exportMethods()` directives in the `NAMESPACE` file are used to export S4 objects.)

Comment: I think `promptClass`, `promptMethods` are in the methods package.

Comment: @MartinMorgan -- Thanks. You're right, of course, and I've edited accordingly.