# Roxygen2 document dependency of a function

Tags: r, roxygen2

I wonder how one should document that a function requires a second function or a package. Are there specific tags do to so or should I just say so n the function description?

```
#' @title Downloads stuff from that place
#' 
#' @details Maybe document the dependency here?
#' 
#' @param stuff Thing to be downloaded
#' @param save_to Where to place the thing
#' @return Nothing. Called for its side effect

download_stuff = function(stuff, save_to) {

    require('RCurl')               # How do document this?

    # thing = download stuff using RCurl
    # write thing to save_to
}
```

Comment: `@seealso ` is probably your best bet

Comment: Actually, I misread slightly. An intra-package dependency is probably best done with ∘seealso@seealso. The requirerequire dependency applies to your entire package, so should be handled in the metadata for the package. I believe it's generally considered bad form to use requirerequire inside a function.... <sigh> assuming of course you are creating a new package :(

Comment: It's noted in the R Extensions manual that `require()` and `library()` should not be used in a package.  If you plan on submitting to CRAN, you'll need to add RCurl to the NAMESPACE file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the idea shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368262/how-to-properly-document-s4-class-slots-using-roxygen2), and wrote the following:

```
#'@section Dependencies: 
#'  \describe {
#'    \item{package_1}
#'    \item{package_2}
#'    \item{package_n}
#'  }
```